# SSIS task return multiple results

Tags: ssis

I need to create a task in SSIS to bring me some records that a certain number of times repeated (for example, an identifier assigned multiple features). The tables where I consult, have millions of records and SSIS lookup returns only one record me, that is when it finds the first match. The others discarded.

A Merge Join is not feasible since it can take hours. I can not filter the result for resutlados I hope.

I must bring records from a table in Oracle and compare identifiers with SQL server and let the records that meet the condition in its entirety (all), not partially (only one)

The Join (inner join) must be between two tables, the first has 10 rows, the second 84 million rows. The result should be inserted into a table that is completely empty

Comment: Conceptually, your main source of data would be the SalesOrder table. You then need to get all the related SalesOrderDetail rows based on the SalesOrderId?

Comment: Exactly. I must bring records from a table in Oracle and compare identifiers with SQL server and let the records that meet the condition in its entirety (all), not partially (only one)

Comment: How many rows are you talking about in the two source tables/queries?

Comment: The Join (inner join) must be between two tables, the first has 10 rows, the second 84 million rows. The result should be inserted into a table that is completely empty.    Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With millions of rows, I think you are going to have trouble completing this task with a cache in memory, which would be faster. You can try creating a lookup task with full cache and see how it goes - if you run out of space, I believe it will fail.

If it suits your business requirements, you can use temporary tables and a merge statement, which can be many times faster than using the Merge Join dataflow task: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280522(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: But the Lookup Task is a synchronous component. 1 input row = 1 output row. They need a 1:many Lookup task which is the challenge here

Comment: Ah, I took this: "meet the condition in its entirety (all), not partially (only one)" to mean that he needed all columns to match, not just the identifier column. But perhaps he means that he needs all the records, as in a 1 to many relationship, as you suggest.

Comment: Tests effected, and if anything, you commented. Thank You!